# Sometimes camera rotates with targeted empty, sometimes not. Why?

Tags: animation, constraints, empty

I have a blend file where the camera, constrained to an empty, rotates when I rotate the empty. This is what I want to happen. I have another blend file where the camera will not rotate when I rotate the empty. Why? Setups appear to be the same in both blend files. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.5, Windows 11

[Camera rotates with empty](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/camera_rotates_with_empty.blend)

[Camera does not rotate with empty](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/camera_does_not_rotate_with_empty.blend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the *Target Z* option:

[image]

Comment: Aha! Thank you! :)